# Quotes ambiguity with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm reading a CSV file that contains errors that I'd like to catch. For example, assume I have this:

```
field1
"I find quotes"" confusing"""
"I find "quotes" confusing"
```

The first line is valid i.e. double quotes within the line are escaped by double quotes. The second line is invalid according to the CSV specification.

When I read in both lines in Pandas however they equate to the same thing:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('quotes.csv')
>>> df['field1']
0    I find quotes" confusing"
1    I find quotes" confusing"
Name: field1, dtype: object
```

Is there a way to catch malformed lines like the second one?

Comment: this may be nit-picky... but is crucial. in your first row the word `qoutes` does not have beginning quotes. is this intended?

Comment: It is intended. It's a contrived example put together to show that malformed CSV data and valid (albeit unusual) CSV data are interpreted by Pandas as equivalent.

Comment: What is "the CSV specification"?  Is there one and only one correct spec on this?  (I really don't know, I am asking.)  It's definitely not the case that pandas handles CSVs the same as other programs (e.g. I know cases where pandas read CSVs differently than excel and stata.  In any event, I don't think that it is a stated goal of pandas to follow any particular CSV reading standard.

Comment: Well, if you could use read_fwf() that would work, but your CSV is probably variable width.  You might have to read in the whole line as a string and then process in python/pandas.

Comment: RFC 4180 relates to CSV. My impression is it's merely a proposal rather than an accepted standard. I'll go with the Python string processing approach.

Comment: For info, I've found Perl's Text::CSV module gives the desired behaviour. It correctly parses line 1 and throws an error for line 2.